# Build a QR Scanner for Ionic React Capacitor app

Tags: ionic-framework, capacitor, ionic-react

I want to build a QR Scanner for my project using Ionic React ver 7. But I cannot find the library that suits my needs. Also, I'm pretty confused by this Capacitor. Have anyone tried to build this? I need a camera preview, and when it recognizes the QR code, it will show a tooltip or something similar of the link or the text. Thanks.

I've tried multiple libraries, but can't seem to find the one that works.

Comment: This question is far too vague and broad in scope for this site. Questions asking *Have anyone tried to build this?* are meaningless - an answer of *Yes, I have tried this* would be a complete answer, but it's unlikely that would be acceptable to you. We also don't accept questions that ask us to recommend or find tools, software libraries, or other off-site resources. SO is for specific questions related to programming (code) or use of a programmer's tool (IDE, compiler, etc.). You may want to revisit the [help] pages to better understand what is acceptable to ask here.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried on 2 plugins Capacitor v5 and up works pretty fine on both Andorid and Ios.

This package will be depricated but working ok anyay,
@capacitor-community/barcode-scanner

This package is recommended for use.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@capacitor-mlkit/barcode-scanning

Below is a working demo.
https://github.com/robingenz/capacitor-mlkit-plugin-demo

Displaying a tooltip or modal or logs, you just wait for the scanner to finish the listening and intercept the results. On the second plugin you can implement a listener and intercept whenever you want.